# How can I modify a column in an Incanter dataset?

Tags: clojure, incanter

I'd like to be able to transform an individual column in an incanter data set, and save the resulting data set to a new (csv) file.  What is the simplest way to do that?

Essentially, I'd like to be able to map a function over a column in the data set, and replace the original column with this result.

Answer (score 5):

You can define something like:

```
(defn map-data [dataset column fn]
  (conj-cols (sel dataset :except-cols column)
             ($map fn column dataset)))
```

and use as

```
(def data (get-dataset :cars))
(map-data data :speed #(* % 2))
```

there is only one problem with changing of column names - I'll try to fix it, when I'll have free time...

Answer (score 5):

Here are two similar functions, both column name and order preserving.

```
(defn transform-column [col-name f data] 
  (let [new-col-names (sort-by #(= % col-name) (col-names data))
        new-dataset (conj-cols
                      (sel data :except-cols col-name)
                      (f ($ col-name data)))]

    ($ (col-names data) (col-names new-dataset new-col-names) )))

(defn transform-rows [col-name f data] 
  (let [new-col-names (sort-by #(= % col-name) (col-names data))
        new-dataset (conj-cols
                      (sel data :except-cols col-name)
                      ($map f col-name data))]
```

And here is an example illustrating the difference:

```
=> (def test-data (to-dataset [{:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 4}])) 
=> (transform-column :a (fn [x] (map #(* % 2) x)) test-data)
[:a :b]
[2 2]
[6 4]

=> (transform-rows   :a #(* % 2) test-data)
[:a :b]
[2 2]
[6 4]
```

`transform-rows` is best for simple transformations, where as `transform-column` is for when the transformation for one row is dependent on other rows (such as when normalizing a column).

Saving and loading CSV can be done with the standard Incanter functions, so a full example looks like:

```
(use '(incanter core io)))

(def data (col-names (read-dataset 'data.csv') [:a :b])

(save (transform-rows :a #(* % 2) data) 'transformed-data.csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

Again: maybe you can use the internal structure of the dataset.

```
user=> (defn update-column
         [dataset column f & args]
         (->> (map #(apply update-in % [column] f args) (:rows dataset))
           vec
           (assoc dataset :rows)))
#'user/update-column
user=> d
[:col-0 :col-1]
[1 2]
[3 4]
[5 6]

user=> (update-column d :col-1 str "d")
[:col-0 :col-1]
[1 "2d"]
[3 "4d"]
[5 "6d"]
```

Again it should be checked in how far this is public API.

Comment: yes, maybe it will be more optimal, although maybe it's better to add corresponding operations on datasets

Comment: This solution has the beauty that it can be adapted to the cases, where each row is of associative data structure, map, or sequence.

Answer (score 2):

***NOTE: this solution requires Incanter 1.5.3 or greater***

For those who can use recent versions of Incanter...

**[add-column](http://liebke.github.io/incanter/core-api.html#incanter.core/add-column)** & **[add-derived-column](http://liebke.github.io/incanter/core-api.html#incanter.core/add-derived-column)** were added to Incanter in 1.5.3 [(pull request)](https://github.com/liebke/incanter/pull/178)

From the docs:

#### [add-column](http://liebke.github.io/incanter/core-api.html#incanter.core/add-column)

"Adds a column, with given values, to a dataset."

```
(add-column column-name values)
```

or

```
(add-column column-name values data)
```

Or you can use:

#### [add-derived-column](http://liebke.github.io/incanter/core-api.html#incanter.core/add-derived-column)

"This function adds a column to a dataset that is a function of
existing columns. If no dataset is provided, $data (bound by the
with-data macro) will be used. f should be a function of the
from-columns, with arguments in that order."

```
(add-derived-column column-name from-columns f)
```

or

```
(add-derived-column column-name from-columns f data)
```

a more complete example

```
(use '(incanter core datasets))
  (def cars (get-dataset :cars))

(add-derived-column :dist-over-speed [:dist :speed] (fn [d s] (/ d s)) cars)

(with-data (get-dataset :cars)
  (view (add-derived-column :speed**-1 [:speed] #(/ 1.0 %))))
```